# Can't shrink windows 10 partition

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, ssd, multi-boot

I tried to shrink my SSD C: partition on Windows, but when I click on "Shrink partition", an error pops up saying "Parameter is incorrect". I don't get any more info. I tried defragmenting the disk to no avail, and checking it for errors doesn't do anything as well. So I can't even choose the size that I'd shrink it with, the error comes right after windows is checking if I can shrink the partition.

I want to shrink the partition so that I can install Ubuntu and dual-boot with it.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Can you provide screenshots so we can see error and maybe the layout of the disk management screen?

Comment: I will tomorrow! I think my C drive exists out of 3 partitions, one of which is where windows is stored at. And for the error: it's just the standard windows warning popup, only saying "variables are incorrect". If you still need them i'l' upload the screenshots tomorrow.

Comment: Why is this tagged ubuntu?

Comment: Oh i'm sorry i want to shrink my partition to dual boot with ubuntu.